# Not inserting into file?

Tags: php

In the following code; upon submitting it should insert "true"; the value of Enabled in the table Bot; though it does not insert anything. This is my code; thanks!
Note: I get this error upon submitting:

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/induadmi/public_html/bot/index.php on line 12

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "connect.php";
$filename = "status.txt";
$select = mysql_query("SELECT Enabled FROM Bot");
$val = mysql_fetch_assoc($select);
echo "<form method='post'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $insertval=$val;
    $fp = fopen($filename,"a+");
    fwrite($fp,$insertval);
    fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

Comment: first don't use mysql functions, use PDO or mysqli. Second `$val` is the result of the query which needs to be iterated over with `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. I know that Jacob's comment makes sense, however even when not iterating, at the very least the query itself should have been written to file.

Comment: Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/induadmi/public_html/bot/index.php on line 12

Comment: What I think is happening is that the file doesn't exist. Create one then try again. I got the same error while testing, it was OK afterwards.

Comment: http://industus.com/bot/status.txt is the file

Comment: Check for file permissions then.

Comment: fopen with the a+ argument instead of w will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Plus, if you're not using the script from inside the same folder as `bot`, then you need to point it to the folder.

Comment: http://industus.com/bot/status.txt and http://industus.com/bot/index.php are the files. Both exist. I changed it to a+

Comment: change status.txt to .\\status.txt and see if it still doesn't let you.

Comment: Still nothing when I do that

Comment: Your undefined index is due to this `if ($_POST['submit']) {` change it to `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` plus, where are you running your code from, which folder?

Comment: This `$filename = "http://industus.com/bot/status.txt";` is incorrect. Use `$filename = "bot/status.txt";` or `../bot/status.txt` depending on the folder you're executing from.

Comment: You also didn't copy my code right. You have `if (isset$_POST['submit']))` which should be `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: ok, now that error means that what you are trying to write to the file is an array not a string, wither cast it to a string (string) or get what you need out of the array and write that.

Comment: var_dump($select), take a look at the object you get back, then call the pieces of the object you want to write to the file with $object->piece and write those.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    $filename = "status.txt";
    $val = mysql_query("SELECT Enabled FROM Bot");
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        $insertval=$val;
        $fp = fopen($filename,"a+");
        fwrite($fp,$insertval);
        fclose($fp);
        }
    echo "<form method='post'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
?>
```

And as said before, use PDO or mysqli.

Also, you REALLY REALLY want to clarify that query and give it some kind of where clause and format your output in a manner that isn't going to be garbage when you write it to a text file.

Here's a simple example of how I use a similar write to file:

```
function logger($output) {
    $log = fopen('.\\UpdateLog.log', "a+");
    fwrite($log, date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ':  ' . $output . "\r\n");
    fclose($log);
}
```

Comment: care to tell me what is actually happening? It should as long as you a) get a result back from the query and B) can get to status.txt

Comment: http://industus.com/bot/ and http://industus.com/bot/status.txt if you go there you can see

Comment: I'll let you take over this one ;-)

Comment: Then the OP is right back to "square one", *as it were*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at [mysql-fetch-assoc on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an **associative array**, fwrite needs a **string**, as the error message suggests.

Since you query for the Enabled field, you should use something like

```
fwrite($fp,$val['Enabled']);
```

PS
You should really consider using either mysqli or PDO.